# logstash elasticsearch ouput plugin script example to add value to array filed?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hello I am getting this error when I try to add value to existing array field in elasticseach, and my logstash output configuration is:

```
elasticsearch {
    document_id        => 1
    action             => "update"
    hosts              => ["X.X.X.X:9200"]
    index              => "test"
    script_lang        => "painless"
    script_type        => "inline"
    script             => 'ctx._source.arrat.add(event("[file][fuid]"))'
}
```

The error i was getting is

error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to execute script", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"script_exception", "reason"=>"compile error", "script_stack"=>["ctx._source.arrat.add(event(\"[file][fuid]\"))", "                      ^---- HERE"], "script"=>"ctx._source.arrat.add(event(\"[file][fuid]\"))", "lang"=>"painless", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Unknown call [event] with [1] arguments."}}}}}}.

Below is the logstash configuration

```
input {

    beats {
        port => "12109"
    }

}
filter {

    mutate {
        id => "brolog-files-rename-raw-fields"
        rename => { "[ts]"             => "[file][ts]"
        "[fuid]"           => "[file][fuid]"
        "[tx_hosts]"       => "[file][tx_hosts]"
        "[rx_hosts]"       => "[file][rx_hosts]"
        "[conn_uids]"      => "[file][conn_uids]"
        "[source]"         => "[file][source]"
        "[depth]"          => "[file][depth]"
        "[analyzers]"      => "[file][analyzers]"
        "[mime_type]"      => "[file][mime_type]"
        "[duration]"       => "[file][duration]"
        "[is_orig]"        => "[file][is_orig]"
        "[seen_bytes]"     => "[file][seen_bytes]"
        "[missing_bytes]"  => "[file][missing_bytes]"
        "[overflow_bytes]" => "[file][overflow_bytes]"
        "[timedout]"       => "[file][timedout]"
        "[md5]"            => "[file][md5]"
        "[sha1]"           => "[file][sha1]"
       }
    }
}

output{
    stdout { codec => rubydebug}

    elasticsearch {
        document_id        => 1
        action             => "update"
        doc_as_upsert      => "true"
        hosts              => ["X.X.X.X:9200"]
        index              => "test"
        script_lang        => "painless"
        script_type        => "inline"
        script             => 'ctx._source.arrat.add(event.[file][fuid])'
    }
}
```

i am getting data in json format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What error do you get ? Please post a minimally reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that code so we may help you. Posting code as a working example helps you by allowing us to focus on the issue.

Comment: Hi Striped thanks for the reply. The error i am getting is error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to execute script", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"script_exception", "reason"=>"compile error", "script_stack"=>["ctx._source.arrat.add(event(\"[file][fuid]\"))", "                      ^---- HERE"], "script"=>"ctx._source.arrat.add(event(\"[file][fuid]\"))", "lang"=>"painless", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Unknown call [event] with [1] arguments."}}}}}}.

Comment: Please edit your post, and do not include your error in comment for readability.

Comment: I tried "script => 'ctx._source.arrat += "%{[file][fuid]}"' ,but instead of adding to array it is appending to the existing string.

Comment: In the script ctx._source.arrat is intentionally not 'array'? If 'arrat' field is not an array but a text it's doing what it was meant to do.

Comment: Thanks @MrSimple got the answer.